# Creating a Function handling Generic Type accessing properties of different Views

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift2

I have 2 views, both sharing some common properties:

```
class View1: UIView
{
    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton
    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton
}

class View2: UIView
{
    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton
    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton
}

class Utils {
    func enableButtons<T>(view: T) {
        if view is View1 {
            let tempView = view as View1
            tempView.button1.enabled = true
            tempView.button2.enabled = true

        } else if view is View2 {
            let tempView = view as View2
            tempView.button1.enabled = true
            tempView.button2.enabled = true
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get rid of the if-else statements in generic function `enableButtons` so that it looks something like the below and works for both views sent as the parameter:

```
class Utils {
    func enableButtons<T>(view: T) {
        view.button1.enabled = true
        view.button2.enabled = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T` needs to be constrained so that the compiler knows that the parameter `view` has two properties `button1` and `button2`.

In order to do that, you need to use a protocol. You use the protocol to show how the two views are related. Therefore, the generic `T` can know about the two buttons:

```
protocol TwoButtonView {

    weak var button1: UIButton! { get set }
    weak var button2: UIButton! { get set }

}
```

Then, have each view conform to the protocol:

```
class View1: UIView, TwoButtonView


class View2: UIView, TwoButtonView
```

Then, rewrite `enableButtons` so that `T` can only conform to the `TwoButtonView` protocol:

```
func enableButtons<T: TwoButtonView>(view: T) {
    view.button1.enabled = true
    view.button2.enabled = true
}
```

**Edit**

@DavidBerry pointed out that you don't have to use generics if you go this route. Instead, you could do this:

```
func enableButtons(view: TwoButtonView) {
    view.button1.enabled = true
    view.button2.enabled = true
}
```

Comment: Almost, note that there's really no reason for the generic in this case, just use: `func enableButtons(view:TwoButtonView) { ... }`

Comment: @DavidBerry Yes, but the OP wanted generics, so I gave him generics. Generics are useful, but sometimes they overcomplicate things.

Comment: I think he was just wanting generics because that's how he originally approached it, but maybe :)

Comment: @DavidBerry Well now he might understand generics better and also some alternatives. I added your suggestion into my answer.

Comment: Thank you @TroyT. Just got into generics.

Comment: Thank you @DavidBerry for the suggestion.

Comment: @AllenSavio generally speaking if you're looking at a problem with an inner and outer type (think an array of X) you want to use generics if the inner type changes and protocols if the outer type changes.